# Why does my TCP server receive more data than the expected from my Flutter client?

Tags: node.js, flutter, image, tcp

I am trying to send pictures from a Flutter application to my Node.js TCP server.

In the flutter application I use a cameracontroller to be able to continously send images.

After some research I understand that CameraImage uses a different format to capture images (YUV_420_888) and that I have to convert it to something different to be able to handle it on the server side.

This is what my Flutter part of code looks like:

```
// Start the image stream and process a frame
    _cameraController?.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
      if (_frameProcessingTimer == null || !_frameProcessingTimer!.isActive) {
        _frameProcessingTimer =
            Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 7), (timer) async {
          final jpgBytes = await convertCameraImageToJpg(image);
          print("Sending ${jpgBytes.length} bytes");

          socket?.write("flutter_debug");
          socket?.write(jpgBytes.length);
          socket?.write(jpgBytes);

          socket?.close();
        });
      }
    });


  Future<Uint8List> convertCameraImageToJpg(CameraImage image) async {
    try {
      // Convert CameraImage to RGB format
      imglib.Image imgData = convertBGRA8888(image);

      // Encode the image as JPG
      Uint8List jpgData = Uint8List.fromList(imglib.encodeJpg(imgData));

      return jpgData;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error converting CameraImage to JPG: $e");
      return Uint8List(0);
    }
  }
```

For the YUV to RGB converting I use flutter_zxing which provides the following function:

```
Image convertBGRA8888(CameraImage image) {
  return Image.fromBytes(
    image.width,
    image.height,
    image.planes[0].bytes,
    format: Format.bgra,
  );
}
```

All seems normal until this point, I add the data I want to send and send it to my node server. For debugging purposes I output the expected image size on both the client and server side and they match. The first 2 "data unit" gets sent successfully (the hardcoded string and the expected image size)

However, the actual image buffer itself seems to differ from the expected.

The server code looks like this: (I wrote a test client in javascript and that worked as expected so I believe I miss something on the Flutter side)

```
const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket: tls.TLSSocket) => {
  console.log('New client connected with address: ' + socket.remoteAddress);

  const client: Client = {
    socket,
    userId: '',
    expectedSize: null,
    buffer: Buffer.alloc(0),
  };

  clients.push(client);

  socket.on('data', (data: Buffer) => {
    if (!client.userId) {
      // First data received, interpret as user id
      client.userId = data.toString();
      console.log(`User ID received: ${client.userId}`);

      // Create directory for the user if it doesn't exist
      const userDir = `${IMAGE_DIR}/${client.userId}`;
      if (!fs.existsSync(userDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(userDir);
      }
      return;
    }

    if (client.expectedSize === null) {
      // Expecting the image size (an integer)
      client.expectedSize = parseInt(data.toString(), 10);
      console.log(`Expecting image of size: ${client.expectedSize} bytes`);
      return;
    }

    // Data received is the image itself

    client.buffer = Buffer.concat([client.buffer, data]);

    // Save the image 
    ...

      // Reset the client for the next image
    client.expectedSize = null;
    client.buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
    client.userId = '';
    }
  });
```

To be clear the expected result is the following:

A Flutter client should be able to continously send data to my server. The data would be a userid, an expected image size, and the image buffer itself.
The server after receiving the data would save the image in a subfolder named the userid.

At the moment, my logs look like this:

The flutter app outputs this:

```
Sending 35694 bytes
```

The node server outputs this:

```
Server is listening on port 3000.
New client connected with address: ::ffff:192.168.1.94
User ID received: flutter_debug
Expecting image of size: 35694 bytes
Received 4108 bytes of total 35694 data
Received 8192 bytes of total 35694 data
....
Received 159431 bytes of total 35694 data
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are assuming that every receive corresponds to one send. You can't assume that with TCP. It is a streaming protocol, not a messaging protocol. Most probably you have received everything that was sent in the first receive, and now you are parsing part of the image data as though it was the length. You need to rethink your protocol such that it has length word prefixes for every datum.

Comment: Use `socket.add` to send bytes. (`write` will convert the bytes to a string first before sending them.) `socket?.add(jpgBytes);`